# what is the difference between while executing in if x>9 and x==10

Tags: java

```
public static void print(int n) {
    int limit=1;
    int x=1;
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=limit;j++){
        System.out.print(x++);    
      if(x>9){
        x=1;
      }
    }
    limit = 2*limit;
    System.out.println();
    }
        }
```

and the other code is

```
public static void print(int n) {
    int limit=1;
    int x=1;
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=limit;j++){
        System.out.print(x++);    
      if(x==10){
        x=1;
      }
    }
    limit = 2*limit;
    System.out.println();
    }
        }
```

the second one doesnot have a time exceed error while the first one has for some input I don't know.

Comment: What is the difference between "bigger than 9" and "equals 10"?

Comment: for which input you are getting the error? Also what is the exact stack trace of the error?

Comment: @Srikant Karnani What is the value of `n`, for you are executing this code snippet?

Comment: @Guy I agree with you but I think OP needs help with _Why he is getting this behavior?_. You may differ from my thought (most of us are, as indicated by downvote :) ). But for me it a valid question even if seems _not appropriate here_. No offence please!!!

Comment: @Srikant Karnani >9 means all values above 9 will pass the condition. ==10 means only 10 will pass the condition.

Answer (score 0):

If ( x > 9 ) will execute when x is greater than 9
If (x == 10 ) will execute only when x equals 10...not above 10 or not below 10